# Test that I have correctly added someone's public key to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh

I've been through quite a few rounds of this over the years:

1. Someone gives me their id_rsa.pub
2. I copy it into `.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. I ask them to test
4. Some time later, they test and report it doesn't work.
5. I mess around with line feeds, permissions etc, go back to step 3.

Is there any way (obviously without asking for their private key) to verify that a public key has been installed correctly?

Answer (score -1):

TROUBLESHOOTING

On your remote server, run the following:

```
ls -la ~/.ssh | grep "authorized_keys"
```

You should see output similar to the following:

```
-rw-------  1 example.com example.com 398 Jul 15 10:32 authorized_keys
```

Note that the directory needs to include the file called `authorized_keys` with `-rw-------` (600) permissions.

Finally, run this command to check the permissions on your .ssh directory:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drwx------   2 example.com example.com     3 Jul 15 10:32 .ssh
```

You should have a folder called `.ssh` with `drwx------` (700) permissions.

If for either of these tests, you get blank output, or a message similar to the following:

```
ls: /root/.ssh: No such file or directory
```

Please repeat Steps 1 and 4-5 above.

[Found this here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644740/using-ssh-keys-on-your-server)

Comment: No, `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` can be world-readable. See `man ssh`, section `FILES`. Those permissions are merely recommended, not required.

Comment: I have never tried it, perhaps you can log in to your client with the key, then ssh back to your server? Just throwing that out there. (Of course if you could do that, then you would have access to the Private key. :))

Comment: What @muru said, and why `grep` `ls` output instead of just using `ls -la ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ? Anyways, the simple presence of these file does not really mean that the keys were installed correctly.

Comment: grepping the ls output :-0 WHY God?